# How do I remove a specific version of Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am just starting with the Ubuntu environment, and I installed Python 2.7.14, but now I see that I have three versions of this program: Python3.6.6; Python2.7.14 and Python 2.7.15rc1.
I want to remove Python2.7.14, but I can't find the specific command for this. I already tried `sudo apt purge python2.7-minimal`, but this uninstalls the 2.7.15rc1 version, and I want to keep it.
What can I use in order to stay with just the 2.7.15rc1 version?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602191/how-to-completely-uninstall-python-2-7-13-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: No, this is not working for this specific problem.

Comment: What’s the problem with having them all installed?