# How to uninstall python 3.7 from Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using `Ubuntu 19.10`, in which there is python of version `3.7`. After the release of `python 3.8`, which I have installed, now I want to uninstall `python 3.7` so that whenever I would call `python3` in my terminal, it would always call `python3.8`?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/45392626 help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you do not touch your default OS python instalation. Other parts of the system may depend on it and there is no way to know if an upgrade can break something, even if it should not.

I also suggest that you learn (if you haven't already, but I suppose you did not because of the question) about using a python virtual environment, like virtualenv. This allows you to setup specific python environments for each project you write. This means each environment can have its own python version, and, besides the standard python lib for that version, any other third-party python lib you would like to install with pip for that project. This isolates projects from each other. You won't break one because of an upgrade of another.

That said, if you want to keep cutting edge with Python versions, make an install from source, and then install it in the system with the altinstall parameter (see the README.rst of the Python distribution. This way all the installed versions are available with different names (the same for pip) and then you create each of your virtual environments with the wanted version. There is a parameter for virtualenv to apply a specific (older) version if you want.

Quoting the README on the "Installing multiple versions" section:

> On Unix and Mac systems if you intend to install multiple versions of Python
>   using the same installation prefix (`--prefix` argument to the configure
>   script) you must take care that your primary python executable is not
>   overwritten by the installation of a different version.  All files and
>   directories installed using `make altinstall` contain the major and minor
>   version and can thus live side-by-side.  `make install` also creates
>   `${prefix}/bin/python3` which refers to `${prefix}/bin/pythonX.Y`.  If you
>   intend to install multiple versions using the same prefix you must decide which
>   version (if any) is your "primary" version.  Install that version using `make
>   install`.  Install all other versions using `make altinstall`.
>   For example, if you want to install Python 2.7, 3.6, and 3.8 with 3.8 being the
>   primary version, you would execute `make install` in your 3.8 build directory
>   and `make altinstall` in the others.

Finally, the other answers are ok to do exactly what you asked, if you still want to.

Answer (score 9):

You do not need to uninstall old version for this.
You need to update your update-alternatives , then you will be able to set your default python version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.4 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 2
```

Then run :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
Set python3.6 as default.
```

Or use the following command to set python3.6 as default:

sudo update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.6
This should do it.

Comment: This is better than uninstalling because system services and other programs might be using the older version of python and depending on it on specific version path

Comment: In case someone needs a more elaborated guide, just change the name of the versions accordingly:
https://tech.serhatteker.com/post/2019-09/upgrade-python37-on-ubuntu18/

Answer (score 6):

> so that whenever I would call python3 in my terminal, it would always call python3.8

You can simply create an alias for Python 3.8 in your `.bashrc` file in your `/home` path.

Open `~/.bashrc` with your preferred editor, and go to the last line.

Append this line:

```
alias python='python3.8'
```

And whenever you call `python` in your terminal, it opens `Python 3.8`.

**Note:** This doesn't work as expected when creating virtual environments with specific version. You might want to keep that in mind.