# Uninstall python3.8 from Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

This is a pretty dumb question, but is **ubuntu** dependent on **Python 3.8**? If it is not, how can I uninstall it from my system?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/13297/1128400)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to delete it? If you need another version of python, just install it and leave 3.8 in case you need it for something else.

Comment: @Michael i don't like to left things that im not using anymore installed on my machine rofl

Comment: Check out askubuntu.com for questions concerning the installation or removal of packages on Ubuntu. This is not a programming question and off-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337891/how-to-uninstall-python-3-7-from-ubuntu-19-10/59346882) 
From @progmatico, it's not recommended that you uninstall builtins on Ubuntu such as Python. You can update Python, but it's not reccomended to uninstall. You can uninstall Python 2.x [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242702/how-to-remove-python-2-from-ubuntu-20-04#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20satisfied%20with,files%20and%20the%20unused%20packages), but unless you have Python 2 installed on your machine, this won't be much help. Unless ROM is tight(if not, I suggest the Raspberry Pi(switchable SD cards)), you don't need to have Python uninstalled.
In summary, you don't need to uninstall Python, it's a great coding language ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall it after installing a `python3*` version as alternative. You have to install `python3.9` available from Ubuntu repository.

```
sudo apt install python3.9
```

[Here is how to set it as default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu/410851#410851) before uninstalling `python3.8`.

Without a python3 installed the system will be unusable.

[Python3 by default](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Python3_by_default)

Answer (score 2):

Don't uninstall python3 in ubuntu as it is depended on many python packages if you delete that terminal, firefox browser,idle , will also delete and at last it will show you authentication error

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33612644)

Comment: THIS IS IMPORTANT! I've killed my gnome, the only solution later is to reinstall linux or launch desktop from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using `apt autoremove` is to remove Python along with its dependencies.

```
sudo apt autoremove python3 -y
```

For more information, check the answer given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527410/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-sudo-apt-get-autoremove-over-a-cleaner-app).

Answer (score -1):

I found the easiest way actually is to simply install the latest pip...

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.8
```