# Change python version in google colab which is connected with google cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am using python 3.7 in google colab, but for some reason when I am connected with a linux server in google cloud the python becomes 2.7. How can I change it? Note that python 3.7 is already installled in the server.

I tried these things but weren't helpful.

```
apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
alias pip='pip3'
```

I checked also these sites https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/setup#linux_2, How do I install Python 3.7 in google cloud shell but didn't solve my problem.

**Edit**
By doing Runtime --> Change runtime I can see only this, which the options are 'non', 'gpu', 'tpu'.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually the answer of my question comes from this post [How to completely uninstall python 2.7.13 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602191/how-to-completely-uninstall-python-2-7-13-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Everyone who have a similar problem the first thing that he/she should do is to unistall python 2.7 by using either

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python python-apt python2.7-minimal
```

or

```
sudo apt purge python2.x-minimal
```

and then install python 3.7, by using

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

sudo apt install -y python3-pip

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

# Confirm the new version of Python: 3
python --version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Python version at the command line by running python --version. In Colab, we can enforce the Python version by clicking Runtime -> Change Runtime Type and selecting python3.

Comment: I can see there only the Hardware accelator. See the edit that I updated my question.

Comment: select GPU as hardware accelerator

Comment: I still have the same problem. Do you have any other idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 is expected to be removed in Debian "testing", the basis of gLinux. This is expected to happen shortly after the next major version, Debian Bullseye, is released.

You need to migrate Python 2.7 code to Python 3 and remove  **python-is-python2** packages you might have installed.

When Python 2.7 is removed from gLinux, **python-is-python2** will be uninstalled.

If you have software that requires `/usr/bin/python` to work, but can be used with Python 3, you should install **python-is-python3**.

You can change Python version by running the following commands in terminal:

```
pip install virtualenv

virtualenv venv --python=python3
```

This only works if you have Python2.7 installed at the system level (e.g. /usr/bin/python2.7).

You can find the path to your Python installation with

```
which python3

virtualenv venv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

And check the version using `python3 –version.`

Comment: Thank you a lot. In the last line of code 'virtualenv venv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3' it says no such file in directory. Do you have any idea which is the problem?

Comment: Will you try using 'virtualenv venv --python = /usr/bin/python3`.